# i want to create user defined function to trim a word in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, trim

how can i trim the word in Javascript.....???

Comment: http://www.infotekka.com/articles/?a=10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the function below 
// Trim function in javascript

```
function Trim(str)
{
    while (str.substring(0,1) == ' ') // check for white spaces from beginning
    {
        str = str.substring(1, str.length);
    }
    while (str.substring(str.length-1, str.length) == ' ') // check white space from end
    {
        str = str.substring(0,str.length-1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Hope it helped...

Answer (score 4):

If you can use jQuery, simply use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

If not, just add a trim method to the String prototype if the browser doesn't support it natively:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, '').replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, '')
    }
}
```

Then you can use `var newstring = somestring.trim();`

Comment: Could you just do `this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+|[\s\xA0]+$/, '')` ?

Comment: At least jQuery does it in the way I did. But why not give it a try? ;)

Answer (score 2):

If by `trim`, you mean remove extra whitepace, put this at the top of your script

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
   return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

And use it like this

```
var thestring  = "  hello  ";
alert(thestring.trim());
```

Comment: Agreed, that is the cleanest way to do it